# Is there a way all browsers support user session deletion using xhr in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to delete a user session once I logout or close the browser in beforeunload function in javascript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('DELETE', LOGIN_URI, true);
req.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $rootScope.XSRF_TOKEN);
req.send(null);
```

This works well in chrome / edge browser, however it fails to work on firefox browsers.
Can anyone please help me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use the Beacon API, but this would be inappropriate for your use case, and cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If I force-quit / kill my browser (no matter which one) no code of the browser and therefore no javascript on any open page can run.

Your login system must not rely on users actively logging out.